# Flutter Web --web-renderer canvaskit stuck in Splashscreen

Tags: flutter, canvaskit

I have been using Flutter Web --web-renderer canvaskit for a project for a long time and it has always worked fine. But today after I update a small change of code, it suddenly broke. It still works fine in debug mode, but when I upload to firebase hosting, in the live server, the screen stuck in splashscreen.

I tried both chrome and Safari on Mac the same issue. If I switches to --web-renderer html, the problem goes away. I have been using flutter_native_splash and I noticed it changed my index.html. However, I have been using it for a while and there was never a problem with Flutterweb. I did not update any package. Does anyone know anything about related issues? I am using Flutter 3.3.10 and Flutter doctor has no problem. As the code runs well, I don't know how to debug the live server. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

use **--web-renderer html** insted of --web-renderer canvaskit

Comment: This won't help. I need to fix canvaskit rendering.